# Use Task Scheduler to email Security Event log file?

Tags: windows-xp, email, windows-task-scheduler

In XP, how can I use the Task Scheduler to cause the Security Event log file to be emailed from a machine?

Answer (score 0):

I would say have the task scheduler call a script.  That script would send the email with the attachment of that log file ( which would have to be predefined in the script).

[See here for more information](http://www.petri.co.il/send_mail_from_script.htm)